# Errors with new version of Kerberos | CentOS 8

Tags: yum, kerberos, centos8

Yesterday all kerberos packages on in my container builds got updated to 1.18.2-5.el8 and 1.17-18.el8 is no longer available.

This is causing some big problems on servers.

Our connections all show

`Pre-authentication failed: No key table entry found for user@domain`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You upgraded to CentOS 8.3, which includes a rebased Kerberos.

To quote from the [RHEL 8.3 release notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/8.3_release_notes/new-features#BZ-1802334):

> #### krb5 rebased to version 1.18.2
>
> The krb5 packages have been upgraded to upstream version 1.18.2. Notable fixes and enhancements include:
>
> - Single- and triple-DES encryption types have been removed.
> - Draft 9 PKINIT has been removed as it is not needed for any of the supported versions of Active Directory.
> - NegoEx mechanism plug-ins are now supported.
> - Hostname canonicalization fallback is now supported (dns_canonicalize_hostname = fallback).
>
> (BZ#1802334)

You didn't say what problems you are having (and you should have!). But I would guess based on experience that you still have ancient stuff in your environment that was using 3DES or DES. Of course all of that stuff should have been reconfigured, upgraded or decommissioned many years ago. Since nobody did, now is the time to do it.

Comment: We didn't upgrade. Our container is locked at tag 8.2.2004

Comment: @DavidWest Eh? Your original post says you upgraded.

Comment: We didn't the whole OS. the OS version is locked.

Comment: @DavidWest This is interesting. I just pulled the centos:centos8.2.2004 image, ran `dnf upgrade` in it, and was upgraded to 8.3. It may be time to have a chat with the CentOS container image maintainers.\

Comment: That doesn’t sound like good behavior for people that need reliable systems

Comment: Wait until you hear about what IBM is doing to CentOS (i.e. killing it off).

Comment: We’ve been keeping up with that news. I hope it moves us towards Canonical.

Comment: I'd sooner take my chances with CentOS Stream than Canonical, but to each their own I suppose. :)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed all our problems:
http://plosquare.blogspot.com/2013/01/solution-for-key-table-entry-not-found.html

Specifically we added

```
default_tkt_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5
default_tgs_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5
```

to the `/etc/krb5.conf`